# How would we more accurately translate 那胸前凸起的完美弧度 (published translation: "perfect curve of the convex in front of her chest")?

Tags: translation

[Reddit's /r/MenWritingWomen](https://www.reddit.com/r/menwritingwomen/comments/flfaxj/he_has_previously_described_her_as_having_good/) laughed at this awful-sounding description of a female character's appearance ([original translation](https://www.novels.pl/novel/MGA/70/Chapter-70-Jealousy.html)):

> Her long and thin eyebrows, water-like eyes, tall and beautiful nose, pink and soft lips, **perfect curve of the convex in front of her chest**, and in addition, her snow-like white skin. It really made people’s heart bump loudly. Even if it was said that she was a descended fairy, it would be correct.

Particularly jarring is the use of "convex" to describe her breasts.  It was translated [from the Chinese](https://novel.zhwenpg.com/r.php?id=278350) (so there's some translation problems):

> 那修长的睫毛，那水润的眼眸，那高挺的琼鼻，那粉嫩的小嘴，**那胸前凸起的完美弧度**，再加上如雪一般的白皙肌肤，真的是美到让人砰砰心跳，说其是仙子下凡也不为过。

My own translation of this would be:

> Those slender eyelashes, those watery eyes, that tall nose, that pink tender small mouth, **that bosom which protrudes like perfect arcs**, and additionally with skin as white as snow. It really is beautiful enough to cause a person's heart to beat **peng peng** and say that she is a descended fairy.

I'm finding this tricky since [凸起](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E5%87%B8%E8%B5%B7) means "to protrude" and "convex", and the 的 indicates it's used as an adjective.  Maybe I'm adding a nice spin on this, and it really does say "convex".

**Question**: How would we more accurately translate 那胸前凸起的完美弧度?

(I reiterate, this question is about **accurately translating** this phrase, not making it sound nice.  *What does it say?* not *What should it say?*)

Comment: Maybe, "the perfect arc protruding from her chest".  But I'm unsure if it's idiomatic English.

Answer (score 1):

那修长的睫毛，
Those slender eyelashes,
那水润的眼眸，
those doe-like eyes,
那高挺的琼鼻，
that exquisite straight nose
那粉嫩的小嘴，
those tender pink lips,
那胸前凸起的完美弧度，
the perfect curve of her ample bosom,
再加上如雪一般的白皙肌肤，
also her snow-white skin,
真的是美到让人砰砰心跳，
really amount to beauty which makes my heart pound,
说其是仙子下凡也不为过。
it is not an overstatement to say, she really resembles an immortal descended to our world.

也不为过: not too much to say, not an overstatement

Must be a lady-boy from Bankok!

Answer (score 0):

How would we more accurately translate 那胸前凸起的完美弧度?

Maybe not more accurately, but another contextual suggestion, like,

那胸前 = the bosom

凸起 = raised up

的完美弧度 = with a perfect curvature.